# Jquery slideToggle not applied to children in menu?

Tags: jquery, menu, parent-child, slidetoggle

Sorry, but I'm a jquery/js noob.

I have this html structure for a toggle menu.

```
<li class="topnavtopitem">
<a href="#" >Topitem</a>
    <ul class="topnavitemtoggle">
        <li class="topnavsubitem"><a href="#" >Subitem</a></li>
        <li class="topnavsubitem"><a href="#" >Subitem</a></li>
        <li class="topnavsubitem"><a href="#" >Subitem</a></li>
    </ul>                   
</li>
```

My jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".topnavtopitem").click(function() {
    $( ".topnavitemtoggle", this).slideToggle( "normal", function() {
    });
});
```

});

I simply can't figure out, how I prevent the slideToggle of beeing triggered when I click a subitem,...

Pls help - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent events from bubbling up the DOM. Set it on your `.topnavsubitem` elements to prevent the click from bubbling up to `.topnavitemtoggle`.

```
$('.topnavsubitem').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z5nhZ/)